# Rendering FullCalendar with database fetched event values using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, database, fullcalendar

I want to render the fulcalendar with some database fetched event values. these values are stored in a array json. But currently what happens is only the calendar is shown but can't see any values on the dates and it gives an error too. Please find the code below.

view.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/core/main.css"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/daygrid/main.css"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/list/main.css"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/timegrid/main.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/core/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/daygrid/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/timegrid/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/list/main.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ]
        });

        calendar.render();
    });
</script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
   <div id="calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

myscript.js

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$window', 'vv', '$http', function ($scope, $window, vv, $http)
{
    $scope.displayVal = [];
    $scope.addEventVal = function()
    {
        //code to get values from db
        $scope.displayVal.push({start:someVal,end:someValue});
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
             events: $scope.displayVal
        });
     }   
}]);
```

And then I get an error saying that **fullCalendar is not a function**.What Have i messed with? Please note that I don't want any other feature apart from just displaying the event values obtained from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After attempting many answers I could be successful in the following process

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/core/main.css"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/daygrid/main.css"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/list/main.css"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/timegrid/main.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/core/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/daygrid/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/timegrid/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../fullcalendar-4.1.0/packages/list/main.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$scope.event = {events: [{
            title:'test1',
            start: '2019-05-05 08:00',
            end: '2019-05-10 08:00'
          },
          {
            title:'test2',
            start: '2019-05-05 12:00'
        }]};
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            events: $scope.event.events,
            plugins: [ 'dayGrid','timeGrid','list' ]
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
</script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
   <div id="calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that I have used only the libraries used in fulcalendar-4.1.0 and it doesn't contain any jquery libraries

Answer (score 0):

fullCalendar is no longer implemented as a jQuery plugin, so you can't write `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({`anymore.

Instead you must refer to your `calendar` variable (i.e. where you wrote `var calendar = ...`. However you may need to give it wider scope outside the `DomContentLoaded` callback in order for that to work.

Also, your code example attempts to re-declare the entire calendar, when what you actually want to do is just add some events to to it.

Here's a version which should work properly:

Part 1:

```
<script>
    var calendar; //give the calendar variable global scope
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ]
        });

        calendar.render();
    });
</script>
```

Part 2:

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$window', 'vv', '$http', function ($scope, $window, vv, $http)
{
    $scope.displayVal = [];
    $scope.addEventVal = function()
    {
        //code to get values from db
        $scope.displayVal.push({start:someVal,end:someValue});
        calendar.addEventSource($scope.displayVal); //add some events to the calendar as a new event source
        });
     }   
}]);
```